# Where information is stored on SMS response

Tags: query, mobileconnect, sms

I have two way sms process to set-up.

I need to know, if i get an sms response to a short code with some variables (dynamic) - where will this response information be stored? Where can it be stored?

Can it be stored in DE?

Can i then query the this data for further response?

thanks

Andy

Yes, it can be stored into a DE. configure Default response and capture using AMPSCRIPT

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps as per the code:

1) Create a DE with the fields such as `mobile`(number), `response`(text), `addeddate`(Date)

2) SET the DE name in the AMPscript below which will be saved in MobileConnect SMS.

3) Below is the AMPscript code developed to match with your scenario. **SMS_RESPONSE_TEST** is a DE that will store the SMS campaigns, depending on the response msg received the user record will be stored in the DE. If the response is empty then the `response` field will be set as **NO** whereas if response is not empty then the actual response will be stored with that mobile number.

4) Also, the DE can be exported to FTP by using the export option in Data Extensions or downloaded if you have contact builder.
 Sample Code:

```
%%[
VAR @msg,@response,@inbound,@DateCheck,@DateCheckLogic
/*Stores the response from the sms*/
SET @inbound = [MSG(0).NOUN(0)]

IF NOT EMPTY(@inbound)
THEN
   SET @msg = "Thanks for Responding. We have recieved your response!"    
UpsertData("SMS_RESPONSE_TEST",1,"mobile",Mobile_Number,"response",@inbound,"addeddate",SystemDateToLocalDate(now()))
ELSE
   SET @msg = "Oops we haven't recieved any response, please try again!"
UpsertData("SMS_RESPONSE_TEST",1,"mobile",Mobile_Number,"response","NO", "addeddate",SystemDateToLocalDate(now()))
ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@msg)=%%
```