# How can I extract information gathered through Mobile Connects Info Capture?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I'm using Mobile Connects 'Info Capture' template to get subscriber information. Once a Subscriber has responded with the data I want, is there a way of using that information outside of Mobile connect (i.e. in a Data Extension and/or Sales/Service Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following options:

- [SMS Detailed report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_sms_message_detail_report.htm&type=5)
- [SMS Message Dataview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5)
- [Ampscript in response writing to a DE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140688/where-information-is-stored-on-sms-response)
- [Mobile filtered list](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_create_a_filtered_list_of_contacts.htm&type=5)